# I am unable to instantiate a String array without values temporarily, so that I can add the values at a later stage

Tags: netbeans, java-me

my code:

```
String [] temp;
temp = {"one","two","three"};
```

I get this error:

```
Illegal start of expression, ';' expected.
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Curly braces, the way you have used them, can only be used in array declaration statements. i.e.

```
String[] temp = {"one","two","three"};
```